# Building the 2009.5 QT project

Tags: c++, qt

I have gotten a legacy project written in 2010.

Currently I have QT 5.7.0 (Windows 10). QT Creator fails to build the project with following error:

> :-1: error: dependent 'c:\Qt\2009.05\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf' does not exist.

All the links that were pointing to 2009.05 installation I found seems to be dead.

So I need a recommendation how to build the project - it could be a link to a 
"2009.05" or some advice for the porting.

Basically I don't have to add much improvements there so it doesn't meter if I have to use old libs or new ones.

I could switch to another IDE if it could ease the porting process.

Comment: You can configure qmake settings path to currently installed path.. Which was tools-> options -> Build & Run -> QT Versions tab -> You can add another path as manually to check qmake path in QT

Comment: Thank you, @SenthilKumar. I will try to do that

Comment: the problem is that I don't have the 2009.05 intallation